# Define Cardinality in OWL across different properties

Tags: owl, protege, cardinality, reasoner

**Is there a way to define the cardinality in OWL across several properties?** The usual syntax would be `property min number class`. I would like to do `(property1, property2) min 2 class`.

Example:
I have a sender with several characteristics (Assistance, Meeting). But the Objectproperty/relation to each characteristic is different (has vs. wants).

[image]

All characteristics are grouped in one class.

[image]

An Attacker is defined as a Sender who has minimum two Characteristics (Characs)
[image]

As seen in the first picture, the reasoner does not infer the individual Sender to be an Attacker. However, when the Assist property is changed, it is inferred.

[image]

**Is there a way to define Attacker with a one cardinality over various Objectproperties?** I checked the OWL references and there is no syntax pointing to such a solution. Maybe there is a workaround by designing the ontology differently?

I could just have one property in this ontology as a trick to use the cardinality. But I don't think that is the intention of ontologies. Would work for the use case but is not elegant at all.

Comment: what does the notation `(property1, property2)` mean? it's not a chain but what is it in your context?

Comment: property1 would be 'has' and property2 would be 'wants'. I would like the cardinality be not only dependent on one of them but on both. However, not as a chain. "if an Sender individual has two or more properties which have 'Characteristics' as their range the Sender individual should be considered an 'Attacker'" - is that helpful?

Comment: How many properties in the set you wish to apply this restriction to? One workaround would be to use (p1 some R and p2 some Q) for all pairs in your set and place your class in the complement of their union, but that quickly becomes unmaintainable.